# How to change the maximum parallelism of an operator in Flink State

Tags: java, state, apache-flink

I want to change the maximum parallelism of Flink Job, the current maximum parallelism in state is 128, I want to change it to 256, I changed the maximum parallelism in key state through state API, but the maximum parallelism of my sink operator is still 128, because there is no state descriptor defined, I can't get the state data from the name of the state descriptor, so I can't change it.How can I change it

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435613/flink-change-max-parallelism-to-existing-job/70436859

Comment: could you be more precise about what you tried and show some of your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum parallelism is a property of the new savepoint you are creating via `Savepoint.create(StateBackend stateBackend, int maxParallelism)`. Individual operators don't have their own maximum parallelism.

If your sink is stateful then it will have a state descriptor somewhere and you can migrate its state. If it's not stateful, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.And you said that in this way, I need to read all the state once, and then write the new path may not be suitable for my scenario, because our operator state involves many data sources。
I changed the maximum degree of parallelism in the key state, and then changed the sink comment of the task to generate a new Savepoint to restore the job. The maximum degree of parallelism was changed to 256. But once If I don’t comment on sink, it will appear "The maximum parallelism(128) of the restored state is lower than the configured parallelism (200)".

Comment: and the current 200 parallelism is my change after restart of。

Comment: I don't understand how you could create a new savepoint with a max parallelism of 256 that still contains state for the sink with the old max parallelism. The new savepoint should only contain whatever state you have migrated over. But you could always change the sink operator's UID so that its state won't be restored.

Comment: Sorry I set 160 instead of 200, but it does not affect this problem.  I looked at the state recovery process, the sink has no state, but contains operatorID, operatorSubtaskStates, coordinatorState, parallelism, maxParallelism, maxParallelism in sink is still 128, not new, and final modification。
What I understand is that it is impossible to change, I use savepoint.removeOperator(“HbaseSink”), and it doesn’t work either。

Comment: This is my code.
 
 ExistingSavepoint savepoint = Savepoint.load(env,
                oldDataPath,
                rocksDbStateBackend);

 BootstrapTransformation<Tuple2<Long, String>> transform =OperatorTransformation.bootstrapWith(dataset)
.setMaxParallelism(maxParallelism).keyBy(x -> x.f0).transform(new MySimpleBootstrapFunction());

 savepoint.removeOperator("HbaseSink")
                .removeOperator("procss")
                .withOperator("procss", transform)
                .write(newDataPath);

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong; I've never tried that approach. Maybe what I did here would work better: https://github.com/alpinegizmo/timing-explorer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/jobs/ChangeBackend.java#L156

Comment: This method can successfully change the maximum degree of parallelism, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad this helped. If you will accept my answer, that will help others find it in the future.